Icon for select all in a dropdown with icons and text
So we have this user management app. People look up users, who can be either active or inactive. And they have icons to indicate that. They are also able to filter those users, and it looks like this

My problem is, that I'm not entirely sure what to do about the status dropdown in terms of the icons. Or more specifically an icon for the All option, as it feels like it's missing something. I could have it without the icons

Which is fine I guess. But it feels wrong not to have them there when it already uses icons for status. What would be a good approach here?

Why don't you display the icons on the right side (instead of the left)? 

Good question. I am now, and feel really silly for not thinking of that

no problem at all
